# How to match PHP tags with Regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, expression

I'm not that good at Regex,

Can you give me a pattern to match any php tags? [`<?`, `<?php`]

if you have a nice and simple guide for Regex i'd be happy to have it too :)

I already tried:

```
'/^(<\?)$/'
```

But it doesn't really help =/

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what `^` and `$` do? They're not decorators that should go in every regex.

Comment: By matching php tag what do you mean? To match only the `<?php` or `<?`

Comment: I guess that <? is enough, I just want to filter it.[It's like an edit box for pages ]

Comment: str_replace will do a pretty good job without regex (avoid regex wherever possible)

Comment: Beware of [the X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what is the problem you are actually trying to solve? If you're trying to avoid people injecting PHP code through a form, then this is almost certainly not how you should be going about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need preg_match_all to match tags, plural. The below will match blocks of PHP and store the code.

```
preg_match_all( '/<\?php(.+?)\?>/is', $php, $blocks );
print_r( $blocks );
```

One issue will be if you happen to have the string '?>' in your code not occuring as a PHP closing tag. Would need to know more about your file(s) to advise.

Comment: )) ???
 <? $text = ' <? $text = " ?> ";  ';  ?>