# Grab the first snippet of php code with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I have several files with 2 php snippets nested with

`<? php code code code ?> <? php code code code ?>`

How can I just grab the first snippet including tags with RegEx?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you executing the regex in PHP as well?

Comment: Are you sure about the space between `<?` and `php`?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say `a.php` has this:

```
<?php code code code ?> <?php mocode mocode mocode ?>
```

Now we can get the first result using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9826656/4233593)

```
<?php

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = file_get_contents('a.php');

$tag1 = '<?php';
$tag2 = '?>';

echo $tag1.get_string_between($fullstring, $tag1, $tag2).$tag2;
```

It won't be visible in the regular browser window since it will be rendered as an invisible HTML tag, but the output will be visible *in source* as:

> `<?php code code code ?>`

Comment: Thanks a ton! I have been trying some differant regexs but getting no where. This is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

How about [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/dY0vE5/4)?

```
$re = "/<\\?php(.+?)\\?>/i"; 
$str = "<?php some code in here ?> <?php some other code in here ?>"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Results in this:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => <?php some code in here ?>
>     [1] =>  some code in here 
> )
> ```

[You also should search and try by your own please!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315444/how-to-match-php-tags-with-regex)